# Display a 3D map image in sceneView

Tags: ios, scenekit

I try to set a 3D map picture to the background of the sceneView in SceneKit Editor View. The result is here
[image]

but when I run into the simulator.
[image]

And I got many errors like this:
`[SceneKit] Error: C3DLightingModelPhysicallyBased not supported by OpenGL renderer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simulator only supports OpenGL, but spherical maps are only available when SceneKit runs on Metal.

You should get the correct behaviour on an iPhone 6s. Just make sure that you haven't specifically requested the OpenGL renderer (in Interface Builder for instance).

Comment: It was my fault. I try to run into my iPad Air. It work, then I understand what's going wrong. Thanks.